# Commit exception stack-trace to database when transaction fails

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have my transactional public method which tries to delete many stuff from database.
Also there is database table, containing information about errors during this deletion process.
However, I need it to work in a way that when there is exception thrown during the deletion process, all deletions will be rolled back and a commit new entry to database with the exception stack trace.
My code looks something like this:

```
class Clazz{
     
     @Transactional
     public void classMethod(){
          try {
               deleteStuff();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               logRepository.save(new ErrorLog(e.getMessage()));
          }
     }
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, this code would not work, because the exception is caught in the try-catch block, so the log will be saved to database, but the deletions would not be rolled back.
I've read about `TransactionSynchronizationAdapter#afterCompletion` method, but there is no way to access the stack trace of the exception thrown from that method.

So my question is, is there any way to catch the exception, save stack trace to database and rollback all the other commits?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.
You can write your own Interceptor.
For that you will want to have your own Annotation:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Inherited
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface LogExceptions {

}
```

Then you have to annotate your Method:

```
class Clazz{
     
     @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
     @LogExceptions
     public void classMethod(){
         deleteStuff();
     }
}
```

And write a Interceptor:

```
@Interceptor
@LogExceptions
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.PLATFORM_BEFORE + 100) //intercept before the TransactionalInterceptor at 200
public class LogExceptionsInterceptor {

    public LogExceptionsInterceptor() {}
    
    @Inject
    LogBean logBean;  //some bean to persist the exception

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        Object result = null;

        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry(); //a entity for the stacktrace
        
        try {
            result = ic.proceed();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            
            StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(s));
            logEntry.setStacktrace(s.toString());
            logBean.persist(logEntry);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Finally you have to activate the Interceptor in your beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0">
    <interceptors>
        <class>your.package.LogExceptionsInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

Here's a link to a good tutorial:
https://rieckpil.de/howto-intercept-method-calls-using-cdi-interceptors/